# Passing custom variable to a list parameter in stepfunctions?

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, list, aws-step-functions

I am trying to make a call to StartTranslationTask, and it takes a parameter for target languagecodes in form of a list

```
aw
```

However, the following fails as it is passed as a literal string

```
"TargetLanguageCodes": ["$.language"]

1 validation error detected: Value '[$.language]' at 'targetLanguageCodes' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 5, Member must have length greater than or equal to 2, Member must not be null] (Service: Translate, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 30d4a91f-5bdf-4302-aae8-9f8355816229)
```

If I try to pass it as a list it fails validation since it is passing a list encoded as a string

```
"TargetLanguageCodes": "$.language"
```

What are my options here? Seems like it should be so easy? This is the input tot the translation task

```
{
  "language": "de",
  "bucket": "mybucket",
  "job_name": "mytranslationjob--2023-07-08-00-42-21-507725"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `.$` suffix to the key to indicate to Step Functions that the value contains a [path substitution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters-keyvalue).  Convert the value to an array with the `States.Array` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html):

```json
"TargetLanguageCodes.$": "States.Array($.language)"
```